# Doing a roll back with multiple MySQLI prepared statement

Tags: php, php5, mysqli

This is my code for doing a roll back with multiple MySQLI prepared statement.

I want to know if anything is wrong with the code.

```
 $newRegistrationDataArray = array(
    "date" => $date,
    "name" => $name,
    "address" => $address,
    "country" => $country,
    "occupation" => $occupation,
    "emailAddress" => $emailAddress,
    "memberID" => $memberID,
    "usename" => $usename,
    "password" => $password,
    "salt" => $salt,
    "secretQuestion" => $secretQuestion,
    "secretAnswer" => $secretAnswer,
    "transactionCode" => $transactionCode,
    "perfectMoneyAccount" => $perfectMoneyAccount,
    "egoPayAccount" => $egoPayAccount,
    "payeerAccount" => $payeerAccount,
    "okPayAccount" => $okPayAccount,
    "bitcoinAccount" => $bitcoinAccount,
    "upline" => $upline,
    "userRegistrationIp" => $userRegistrationIp,
    "status" => $status
);

public function CreateNewAccount(&$newRegistrationDataArray){ ///note the &

    /* set autocommit to off */
    $this->dbConnection->autocommit(FALSE);

    $stmt1=$this->dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `members` (date,name,address,country,occupation,emailAddress,memberID,usename,password,salt,secretQuestion,secretAnswer,transactionCode,perfectMoneyAccount,egoPayAccount,payeerAccount,okPayAccount,bitcoinAccount,upline,userRegistrationIp,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt2=$this->dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `membertotalfinancialstatus` (memberId) VALUES (?)");

    /* variable needed */
    $memberId = $this->generateMemberId(); // a private function that generate member id
    $date = $newRegistrationDataArray['date'];
    $name = $newRegistrationDataArray['name'];
    $address = $newRegistrationDataArray['address'];
    $country = $newRegistrationDataArray['country'];
    $occupation = $newRegistrationDataArray['occupation'];
    $emailAddress = $newRegistrationDataArray['emailAddress'];
    $usename = $newRegistrationDataArray['usename'];
    $password = $newRegistrationDataArray['password'];
    $salt = $newRegistrationDataArray['salt'];
    $secretQuestion = $newRegistrationDataArray['secretQuestion'];
    $secretAnswer = $newRegistrationDataArray['secretAnswer'];
    $transactionCode = $newRegistrationDataArray['transactionCode'];
    $perfectMoneyAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['perfectMoneyAccount'];
    $egoPayAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['egoPayAccount'];
    $payeerAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['payeerAccount'];
    $okPayAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['okPayAccount'];
    $bitcoinAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['bitcoinAccount'];
    $upline = $newRegistrationDataArray['upline'];
    $userRegistrationIp = $newRegistrationDataArray['userRegistrationIp'];
    $status = $newRegistrationDataArray['status'];
    /* variable needed */

    $stmt1->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssss',$date,$name,$address,$country,$occupation,$emailAddress,$memberID,$usename,$password,$salt,$secretQuestion,$secretAnswer,$transactionCode,$perfectMoneyAccount,$egoPayAccount,$payeerAccount,$okPayAccount,$bitcoinAccount,$upline,$userRegistrationIp,$status);
    $stmt2->bind_param('s',$memberId);

    try
    {
        if( ($stmt1->execute() == false) OR ($stmt2->execute() == false)){

            /// close statement, roll back and throw an exception
            $stmt1->close();
            $stmt2->close();

            $this->dbConnection->rollback();
            throw new Exception("AN INTERNAL ERROR HAS OCCURED. TRY AGAIN LATER.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $error=$e->getMessage();
        throw new Exception($error);    
    }

    $this->closeDBConn;
}
```

Comment: Does it work as intended?

Comment: I am not just sure about rolling back the 2 statement.      if( ($stmt1->execute() == false) OR ($stmt2->execute() == false)){

            /// close statement, roll back and throw an exception
            $stmt1->close();
            $stmt2->close();

            $this->dbConnection->rollback();
            throw new Exception("AN INTERNAL ERROR HAS OCCURED. TRY AGAIN LATER.");
        }

Comment: If it doesn't work then this is off-topic for CodeReview and belongs on StackOverflow (it's not very clear from your comment whether it does or not)

Comment: +1 for nicely written, easy to read PHP. I'm sure you have your reasons for writing this in PHP, but have you looked into [MySQL built-in transaction language](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)?

Comment: @DanPantry. it is not about working, I only wanted to be sure if what i wrote is OKAY.

Comment: Just making sure, your comment was a bit ambiguous. :-)

Comment: Well, if your code doesn't work it would belong on StackOverflow, or Programmers if it concerns design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function CreateNewAccount(&$newRegistrationDataArray){ ///note the &


    /* variable needed */
    $memberId = $this->generateMemberId(); // a private function that generate member id

    // that is lots of repetitive code, lazy way is use extract,
    // although can be dangerous if you can't trust data in $newRegistrationDataArray
    extract($newRegistrationDataArray);

//    $date = $newRegistrationDataArray['date'];
//    $name = $newRegistrationDataArray['name'];
//    $address = $newRegistrationDataArray['address'];
//    $country = $newRegistrationDataArray['country'];
//    $occupation = $newRegistrationDataArray['occupation'];
//    $emailAddress = $newRegistrationDataArray['emailAddress'];
//    $usename = $newRegistrationDataArray['usename'];
//    $password = $newRegistrationDataArray['password'];
//    $salt = $newRegistrationDataArray['salt'];
//    $secretQuestion = $newRegistrationDataArray['secretQuestion'];
//    $secretAnswer = $newRegistrationDataArray['secretAnswer'];
//    $transactionCode = $newRegistrationDataArray['transactionCode'];
//    $perfectMoneyAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['perfectMoneyAccount'];
//    $egoPayAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['egoPayAccount'];
//    $payeerAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['payeerAccount'];
//    $okPayAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['okPayAccount'];
//    $bitcoinAccount = $newRegistrationDataArray['bitcoinAccount'];
//    $upline = $newRegistrationDataArray['upline'];
//    $userRegistrationIp = $newRegistrationDataArray['userRegistrationIp'];
//    $status = $newRegistrationDataArray['status'];
    /* variable needed */


    try
    {
        /* set autocommit to off */
        $this->dbConnection->autocommit(FALSE);

        $stmt1=$this->dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `members` (date,name,address,country,occupation,emailAddress,memberID,usename,password,salt,secretQuestion,secretAnswer,transactionCode,perfectMoneyAccount,egoPayAccount,payeerAccount,okPayAccount,bitcoinAccount,upline,userRegistrationIp,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt1->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssss',$date,$name,$address,$country,$occupation,$emailAddress,$memberID,$usename,$password,$salt,$secretQuestion,$secretAnswer,$transactionCode,$perfectMoneyAccount,$egoPayAccount,$payeerAccount,$okPayAccount,$bitcoinAccount,$upline,$userRegistrationIp,$status);

        // failure is unexpected, so lets use exceptions to handle it
        if ($stmt1->execute() == false) {
            throw new Exception('Statement 1 Failed');
        }

        $stmt2=$this->dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO `membertotalfinancialstatus` (memberId) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt2->bind_param('s',$memberId);

        if ($stmt2->execute() == false) {
            throw new Exception('Statement 2 Failed');
        }

        // tidy up
        $stmt1->close();
        $stmt2->close();

        // is it normal to close connection at this level? or do you leave it open for other requests
        $this->closeDBConn;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // any sort of exception and we should rollback?
        // either that or subclass exception and handle each exception type differently
        $this->dbConnection->rollback();

        // whats the point of this, just re-throw the same exception?
        // $error=$e->getMessage();
        // throw new Exception($error);
        throw $e;
    } finally {
       // if you have php 5.5 you can do your tidy up here, although if 
       // an exception has occured, you probably don't care about freeing stmt's as
       // they all end up in the garbage anyway

        // tidy up
        //$stmt1->close();
        //$stmt2->close();
    }

}
```